# How do JS interpreters know when to abandon a function's variable scope

Tags: javascript

i have a fundamental question concerning JS scripting. When it comes to this...

```
var myClass = {
  foo: function() {
    var memoryConsumingVariable = [...];
    someAsyncFunction(function(x){
      doStuff();
    }
  },

  bar: function() {
    var memoryConsumingVariable = [...];
    doStuff();
  }
}
```

Of course everytime i call myClass.foo() or myClass.bar() the interpreter creates a new variable scope for this invocation. When it comes to calling bar() things are clear.. After the function finished the interpreter can easily delete the scope removing memoryConsumingVariable from memory because no more references to the variable exist.

But how about calling foo()? How does the interpreter know when this scope is not needed any more? someAsyncFunction() could call it's callback more oftenly or pass it to another function as callback itself.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your javascript is wrong and won't compile. Can you correct it ? You use `=` instead of `:` and you miss a parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Garbage collection will not handle `foo` because it's defined without `var`, thus hoisting it to global scope.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: It's not defined at all because  the `=` is a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah I should clarify: if that wasn't inside an object and was legal syntax*

Comment: @Fabian: functions hold a reference to their outer lexical environment, so think of each scope as an object, and each nested scope as having a pointer to their outer scope. This forms a tree structure, so they can just reference count. As to the actual mechanics of a particular implementation, I don't know.

Comment: Yes right, of course you use : instead of =.

Comment: So the callback function will have a reference counter as well keeping the consumingVariable alive. Thank you.

Comment: @Fabian: You can think of it that way (though it would be the enclosing scope having the counter, which the nested functions would increment and decrement). What actually happens is implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the real code is the following one :

```
var myClass = {
  foo : function() {
    var memoryConsumingVariable = [...];
    someAsyncFunction(function(x){
      doStuff();
    });
  },

  bar : function() {
    var memoryConsumingVariable = [...];
    doStuff();
  }
}
```

When you call `myClass.foo()`, `memoryConsumingVariable` will stay in the memory while the anonymous function `function(x){ doStuff(); }` is in the memory too. The garbage collector can't remove `memoryConsumingVariable` because it is in the reachable environment of the anonymous function.

If no more pointer can give access to this anonymous function, the garbage collector will remove the anonymous function and will then remove `memoryConsumingVariable` because no one can access it anymore.

Comment: @Magnus, how does the GC manage reachable data? I heard there is  a hidden reference to the environment/heap containing the data. Is that it? Can you elaborate on that as well?

Comment: I'm not an expert of the garbage collector behaviors sorry. I just know it works like that, but i don't know how it handle it internaly.